# step by step analysis for GDP forecast with PLS and SAS

Tags: dataset, econometrics, sas, partial-least-squares

I'm currently trying to do a forecast of GDP , although I'm new to the econometric field , with SAS and the Partial Least Square method.

My question is the following:

Does anyone have any articles that will give me a better understanding of what is needed in term of data preparation , the coding and any hints.

I know I'm bit vague but my understanding is vague on how to use PLS in that occasion.

Thank you in advance for any tips you will be able to give me.

Comment: I don't need code , I need more of a paper of someone who went through the process and is explaining his or her methods and the subsequent explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try:

- "Partial Least Squares Regression: A Tutorial". Paul Geladi, Bruce Kowalski. (1986). Analytica Chimica Acta. Volume 186. Pages 1-17.

The paper is freely available on google scholar. 
http://www.udel.edu/chem/analytical/cumes/text-partial%20least-squares%20regression.pdf

The paper gives a nice history of the method, explains the algorithm well (comparing it to multiple regression and principal component regression), and gives references to other seminal work in this area. The paper has been cited 4000+ times. One downside...it's pretty old.